# Skip observations that been read once from a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, duplicates, append, skip

i read a CSV file with few columns and created a class for those columns:

```
  class member:
    name = ""
    vdate = []

data = []
for column in columns:
    m = member()
    m.name = column[1] + " " + column[2]
    m.date = int(column[5]
```

Now, i'm trying to skip lines that have been read once from m.name, the skiped lines wont be append to

data = []

However, after I skiped those lines, I want the date value in the skip lines to be append to  the vdate [] in the class.

I tried:

```
  if m.name != m.name:
    data.append(m)
else:
    continue and vdate.append(m)
```

did not worked.

Comment: aggregate your data using a groupby then iterate over the data set into the list

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that a Class is the best way to go about this.

I would just have a simple dict to hold the name as a key and the date as a value. And then just check if each new line is in the dict. If it is not add it to the dict, and if it is just the date to a another list.

So that should give you a dict with key value pairs of names and dates, and a list with the dates where the name is already in the dict.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about "And then just check if each new line is in the dict. If it is not add it to the dict, and if it is just the date to a another list"

Comment: something like:
if name not in my_dict.keys():

Comment: something like:

`if name in my_dict.keys():
   vdata.append(date)`

where vdata is your list of dates where the name is already in the dict.

Comment: thank you so much for trying to help, it does not work:

`class member:
    name = ""
    date = []

data = []

import csv
file = open("vaccination.csv")
columns = csv.reader(file)

next(columns)  
    
for column in columns:
    m = member()
    m.name = column[1] + " " + column[2]
    m.date = int(column[5])
    if m.name in data():
        if m.name in data.key():    m.date.append(m)
    else:
        data.append({"name": m.name, "date": m.date})`